# How to call function on UIPopViewController dismiss in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I am using UIPopViewController in iPad application,I can dismiss popviewcontroller using tap on screen.But,I am trying to call function for dismiss,is that possible?How can I call function?Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to dismiss the popover programatically, you can simply call:

```
[popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

If you are trying to detect whether a user has dismissed a popover by tapping on the screen, you can make use of the UIPopoverControllerDelegate method `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:`

First, set the viewController which presents the popover as delegate:

```
popover.delegate = self;
```

Then implement the method:

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    //Perform necessary action here.
}
```

Have a look at the UIPopoverControllerDelegate reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverControllerDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPopoverControllerDelegate/popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:).